# Error "Property Listeners cannot be empty" occurs when deploy ruby-on-rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am newbie in AWS Cloudformation. My Elastic Beanstalk Worker uses Ruby on Rails. The EB is a Stack based on cloudformation template.
I don’t know why, when I deploy (`eb deploy`) recently, Event gave the following error message:

[image]

The `AWSEBLoadBalancer` is not in `Resources:` of the template. But I find it in `.ebextensions` of the source code.

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Properties:
      AccessLoggingPolicy:
        EmitInterval: 5
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName:
          Ref: LogsBucket
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    DependsOn: "LogsBucketPolicy"

  LogsBucket:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"

  LogsBucketPolicy:
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: LogsBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          -
            Action:
              - "s3:PutObject"
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                ? "Fn::FindInMap"
                :
                  - Region2ELBAccountId
                  -
                    Ref: "AWS::Region"
                  - AccountId
            Resource:
              ? "Fn::Join"
              :
                - ""
                -
                  - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                  -
                    Ref: LogsBucket
                  - /AWSLogs/
                  -
                    Ref: "AWS::AccountId"
```

Can you please  give me some hints to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show the template?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for checking my question. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you are missing [Listeners](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#cfn-ec2-elb-listeners). With the `Listeners` your balancer definition would be something like (need to modify to your own settings):

```
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: 80
          InstanceProtocol: HTTP
          LoadBalancerPort: 80
          #PolicyNames: 
          #  - String
          Protocol: HTTP
          #SSLCertificateId: String
      AccessLoggingPolicy:
        EmitInterval: 5
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName:
          Ref: LogsBucket
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    DependsOn: "LogsBucketPolicy"
```